# On HTC Desire S, soft keyboard not popping up on EditText focus

Tags: android, android-layout, android-edittext, android-keypad

I am having an EditText with `imeOptions="actionSearch"`. Now when I click on EditText, the keyboard does not pop up in some of HTC Devices, like HTC Desire S & HTC Incredible. EditText xml is as follow:

```
<com.myapp.utilities.font.DroidSansEditText
                    android:id="@+id/txtSearchByName"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_weight="0.60"
                    android:background="@drawable/edittext"
                    android:ellipsize="end"
                    android:gravity="left|center_vertical"
                    android:hint="@string/provider_practice"
                    android:imeOptions="actionSearch"
                    android:inputType="textCapWords"
                    android:paddingLeft="10dp"
                    android:paddingRight="5dp"
                    android:singleLine="true"
                    android:tag="byName"
                    android:textColor="#a19d93"
                    android:textSize="15.5sp" />
```

`DroidSansEditText` is the custom `EditText` having `droid-sans font`. The DroidSansEditText is as follow :

```
public class DroidSansEditText extends EditText {
    public DroidSansEditTextView(Context context) {
        super(context);     
    }

    public DroidSansEditTextView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    public DroidSansEditTextView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
    }

    @Override
    public void setTypeface(Typeface tf, int style) {
        if (!isInEditMode()) { //For Graphical layout of xml in eclipse 
            // here Bold style is handled. Same way we can handle italic style
            if (style == 1) { // if bold (Style Constant, normal = 0 | bold = 1
                                // | italic = 2)
                tf = Typeface.createFromAsset(getContext()
                        .getApplicationContext().getAssets(),
                        "DroidSans-Bold.ttf");
            } else {
                tf = Typeface.createFromAsset(getContext()
                        .getApplicationContext().getAssets(), "DroidSans.ttf");
            }
            super.setTypeface(tf, 0);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

maybe because actually you do not set typeface if this EditText is in edit mode?

I mean, why do you need that:

```
 if (!isInEditMode())
```

if in edit mode you want to set another typeface, write **else** statement and set this another typeface in it.

Because as for now - if TextView is in Edit Mode you don't call super.setTypeface(); so you just override method and do nothing in it. Please try and let me know

Comment: Thanks for reply. Actually I have no clue what `EditMode` does to `EditText`. I put that condition because without that in Eclipse, I was not able to see EditText properly in graphical mode.

Comment: then provide else statement for that if, where You call super.setTypeFace() for instance

Comment: Provided else block. Also for being sure I had explicitly opened keyboard on touch of editext using Input `InputMethodManager`. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

There is a way to show and hide the keyboard when clicked on edit text to type something.Find below the lines for showing the keyboard implicitly.

```
InputMethodManager mgr = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);

mgr.showSoftInput(editText, InputMethodManager.SHOW_IMPLICIT);
```

where edit Text is the Edit Text you are using.and to hide it when touched somewhere else on the screen just do this.Take the top most layout of your screen and implement this on on Touch method of your top layout so that when touched somewhere else other than the edit text keyboard gets dismissed.

```
InputMethodManager mgr = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);

mgr.hideSoftInputFromWindow(editText.getWindowToken(), 0);
```